# FutureBuilder has empty snapshot despite Future returns proper data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have FutureBuilder widget as Scaffold's body and I want to display a list of widgets when database returns required info but while database is properly returning data the FutureBuilder does not show any widgets(like CircularProgressIndicator or required List as it finishes its job). Code shown below:

```
Future<List<Widget>> getList() async{
  List<Widget> list = [];
  var db = dbMethods();
  db.getConnection().then((conn) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    var result = await conn.query("select * from info", []);

    for(var row in result) {
      var item = BilbordItem(
          firm: row[2],
          constructionType: row[3],
          demonstrationType: row[4],
          lat: double.parse(row[5]),
          long: double.parse(row[6]),
          sizeX: double.parse(row[7]),
          sizeY: double.parse(row[8]),
          address: row[9],
          positionRate: int.parse(row[10]),
          colorsRate: int.parse(row[11]),
          passabilityRate: int.parse(row[12]),
          typeRate: int.parse(row[13])
      );
      print(item.address);  //here i was checking if database fetch is working and it does print required info
      list.add(item);
    }
    conn.close();
  });
  return list;
}

class _ListPage extends State<ListPage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Список билбордов"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getList(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                  if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: snapshot.data,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  else if(snapshot.hasError){
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red,),
                            Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Text("Empty"),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
            },
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to `await db.getConnection().then(...` but actually if `getList()` is an `async` method, simply use `await` instead of `.then(...`

Comment: Thank you, this should be the answer

Comment: i hope you followed my second advice (i mean to remove `.then`)?

Comment: well yes but actually no :) gonna do that now

Comment: `final conn = db.getConnection(); var result = await conn.query("select * from info", []); ...` - note you dont need `await Future.delayed`

Comment: thanks, btw `await Future.delayed` is needed because mysql1 library has a bug and doesn't work whithout that string

Comment: ooops, of course it should be `final conn = await db.getConnection();`